# JSON syntax in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, json

I have written the following Javascript but get the error 'Invalid JSON primitive: strSeason'.  The rest of the syntax seems fine but I can't seem to get the 'data' parameter right.  Can anybody help me with the syntax?

```
TagBuilder script = new TagBuilder("script");
            script.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
            script.Attributes.Add("language", "javascript");
            // ReSharper disable LocalizableElement
            script.InnerHtml = @"

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                async: true,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'html',
                url: '/en-US/" + areaName + '/' + controllerName + '/' + actionName + @"',
                data: " + "{strSeason:'" + season + "', strTeam:'" + team + @"'},
                beforeSend: function(xhr){
                $(this).addClass('ajaxRefreshing');
                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Client', 'jQuery');
                },
                success: function(html){
                $(this).html(html);
                },
                complete: function(){
                $(this).removeClass('ajaxRefreshing');
                }
            });

        ";
```

Comment: you can validate your json string http://jsonlint.com

Comment: Shouldnt the datatype be "json"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap the names in quotes

```
data: " + "{'strSeason':'" + season + "', 'strTeam':'" + team + @"'},
```

EDIT: You may just need to send the JSON string so wrap entire string in quotes.

```
data: " + "\"{'strSeason':'" + season + "', 'strTeam':'" + team + "'}\"" +@",
```